# PHP calling in more than 1 Tweet

Tags: php, api, loops, twitter, foreach

I have this code that creates an array of tweets based on the count value (currently set to 5) however, when I try to display the tweets I get nothing but the word Array repeated 5 times (and not the actual tweets), could anyone help me troubleshoot what I'm doing wrong?

By the way, if I change the count to 1 and just echo the variable $tweet, I get the latest tweet display correctly.

```
function get_tweet() {

require 'parts/tmhOAuth.php';
require 'parts/tmhUtilities.php';

$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
 'consumer_key' => 'taken out for security purposes',
 'consumer_secret' => 'taken out for security purposes',
 'user_token' => 'taken out for security purposes',
 'user_secret' => 'taken out for security purposes',
 'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => false
));

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('GET', $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/statuses/user_timeline'), array(
'screen_name' => 'designernewsbot',
'count' => '5'));

$response = $tmhOAuth->response['response'];
$tweets = json_decode($response, true);

// This is to create links in my webpage if links are specified in the tweet
$tweet = $tweets[0]['text'];
$tweet = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $tweet);
$tweet = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>", $tweet);
$tweet = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", $tweet);

foreach($tweets as $tweet):

    echo $tweet;

endforeach;


}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($tweets);` output?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump the $tweet and see what is inside of it?

Comment: @DavidLandes I have just tried this within the foreach loop and get back what seems to be a hell of a lot of data not just the tweets but data about the user who did the tweeting etc. Not sure what I'm doing to be honest... Any ideas?

Comment: @AmalMurali data similar to the var_dump I did, see comment above

Comment: @egr103: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `foreach` loop. You're trying to print `$echo` inside the loop, which is an array. So you'll receive an `Array to string conversion` error.

A `for` loop seems more suitable in this case:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($tweets); $i++) { 
    echo $tweets[$i]['text']."\n";
}
```

**Update:**

To also show the links in tweets, you can do:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($tweets); $i++) { 
    //echo $tweets[$i]['text']."\n";
    $var = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $tweets[$i]['text']);
    $var = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_new\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>", $var);
    $var = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", $var);
    echo $var."\n";
}
```

I've tested this and it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! How do I output this as an Unordered list so I have control over its appearance (UL)?

Comment: @egr103: the same way you'd do that for other variables? [Example](http://hastebin.com/nayuqoxugu.xml).

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have noticed though that this for loop isn't outputting the links in tweets as links. Why would this be? See the lines with preg_replace in my code in my question. Any ideas?